# About conversion between pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

What does actually "conversion between pointers" mean ? If I have something like `type_1* x, type_2* y`  and call `dynamic_cast<type_1*>(y)` (the question is not about dynamic cast, I used it because it is a function that works well with pointers casting as far as I know) what will it return ?  A pointer of type `*type_1` that points to the same object as y (or `NULL`, of course) ? Is this true? Is there anything more I should know to understand these castings between pointers ?

Comment: It will result in compilation error. Do you mean `dynamic_cast<type_1*>(y)`?

Comment: Of course, edited now.

Comment: some code example would help to clarify the question. What a `dynamic_cast` does depends very much on what `type_1` and `type_2` are and whether there is some relation between them, see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Comment: My question is in fact, what does casting between pointers mean ? If I have ```p1* pointer_1```and ```p2* pointer_2```, what does ```any_function_cast<p1*> (p2) do```? Does it return a pointer of type p1* that points to the same object as p2? If the cast is possible, of course.

Comment: @IonNebunu Depends very much on what `type1` and `type2` are and what type of casting you are using...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some time ago I saw the code that controlled the first Apollo mission. It was all-assembly, the C, lat alone C++, did not exist at those days. We can imagine that in that assembly, all they had at their disposal was registers and raw memory that had to be managed manually.

In modern, non-assembly languages, including C/C++, the compiler frees you from the burden of manual memory management. The memory for named variables, like in

```
int x = 0;
```

is allocated and deallocated automatically. Also, you don't need to bother about memory that is needed temporarily, e.g., during  some complex computations. In C/C++ these "usual" variables are accompanied by pointers that allow you to access this automatically or semi-automatically managed memory indirectly. Moreover, you need pointers to access the heap-allocated ("nameless") memory (remember `operator new`?).  And this is almost all you should know about them. The syntax is known: the asterisk `*`, the "arrow" `->` and the ampersand `&`. It's the compiler's duty to protect you from doing probably stupid operation on pointers, like using them as if they are just integers (a popular trick in 1970s) or using them as if they pointed to something else that you've declared. Declaring a pointer means that you declare the whole set of operations on it. To protect you from accidental shooting your foot off, the compiler forbids such horrible things like automatic assignments of pointers of different types.

However, **you** are the master of the compiler, not the opposite, so you can take the full control. This is where pointer conversion steps in. On the one hand, by ussing pointer conversion, you **can** temporarily switch off all the safeties the creators of the compiler has prepared for you. On the other hand,  with a suitable cast, you can guarantee that your program is correct!

The really important question is: which operations involving pointer conversions are guaranteed to be safe?

The first, a bit surprising thing is: there are several types of pointers, which need not be mutually compatible:

- pointer to data
- pointer to (free) function
- pointer to data member
- pointer to member function
- `void*` pointer

Their internal representation, or even the number of bits they occupy, need not be the same!

So, what is allowed?

The C language loves to use `void*` as the means of passing data of arbitrary type.   So you can be sure that you can convert any data pointer to `void*` and then back to its original type and this will work.  Similarly with pointers to functions.

Another place where pointer conversions are natural is low-level serialization. Many function in both C and C++ work on buffers declared as `char*` or `const char*`. From this you can infer that you should be able to convert any pointer to data to `char*` and it will work as expected.

The third common pointer conversion is when you deal with inheritance, especially in the context of classes with virtual functions. Here comes `dynamic_cast` to cast a pointer in the potentially "dangerous" way along the inheritance tree.

There are also other casts that are safe and others that may lead to undefined behavior or even segmentation fault. For example, pointers to `int` are often casts to or from  pointers to `float` and it usually works, e.g., in AVX or GPU programming. Correctness of these particular casts are guaranteed by hardware vendors rather than the C++ standard.

What dangers are there if you leave the land of safe casts? For example, you cast a pointer to function to `void*` and then this pointer to `char*`. If you try to dereference this pointer, let alone write through it, your program is doomed to die immediately.  Similarly dangerous conversions are between pointers to data and pointers to members. Don't do that. Also, don't use pointers to cast pointers to integers etc. This is generally the land of undefined behavior, unless you carefully consulted the standard and are sure the thing you're doing is safe.

To sum this long story up: pointer conversion **usually** generates no code, but sometimes it does. See the examples below.

**EXAMPLES**

**1. Inheritance. Static cast vs. dynamic cast.**

Suppose we have `XY` derived from both `X` and `Y`:

```
struct X
{
    float x;
};

struct Y
{
    float y;
};

struct XY : public X, public Y
{
    float xy;
};
```

Then this code:

```
    XY a;
    std::cout << static_cast<X*>(&a) << "\n";
    std::cout << static_cast<Y*>(&a) << "\n";
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<X*>(&a) << "\n";
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<Y*>(&a) << "\n";
    std::cout << &a << "\n";
```

may produce these results:

> 0x7fffc7d75dcc
> 0x7fffc7d75dd0
> 0x7fffc7d75dcc
> 0x7fffc7d75dcc
> 0x7fffc7d75dcc

So, `static_cast` does change the "value" of the pointer! At the same time, `reinterpret_cast` only "reinterprets" the bits stored in a pointer variable / register, but does not modify them.

Interestingly, if we defined a virtual method in `Y`, the same code would reveal a reversed order of `X` and `Y` inside `XY`:

> 0x7ffc6a45764c
> 0x7ffc6a457640
> 0x7ffc6a457640
> 0x7ffc6a457640
> 0x7ffc6a457640

So, the order of embedding the base classes in multiple inheritance seems to be undefined / implementation-dependent.

**2. casts to integer types**
The standard allows to cast pointers to and from  integer types of sufficient length.

Casts of "C-style pointers" to integer types work as expected:

```
    XY a;
    std::cout << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&a) << "\n";
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&a) << "\n";
```

yields, for example,

> 7fff84f5a6cc
> 0x7fff84f5a6cc

as expected. But he standard does not guarantee this.

**3. pointers to data members**
This case is more interesting: pointers to members cannot be cast to anything. But there's a workaround:

```
    XY a;
    float XY::* mptr_xy = &XY::xy;
    float XY::* mptr_x = &XY::x;
    float XY::* mptr_y = &XY::y;
    std::cout << *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&mptr_x) << "\n";
    std::cout << *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&mptr_y) << "\n";
    std::cout << *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&mptr_xy) << "\n";
```

This may give the following result:

> 0
> 4
> 8

This shows that the pointers to members are offsets into objects memory rather than pointers to RAM. If we add a virtual destructor to `Y` we may get this:

> 12
> 8
> 16

The offsets have changed, making room for  `vptr` and moving `Y` to the front.  If both `X` and `Y` have virtual destructors, a possible  result is this:

> 8
> 24
> 28

Conclusion: pointers to members are completely different beasts than standard pointers.

**4. Dynamic casts**

Suppose both `X` and `Y` have virtual destructors. This code:

```
    XY xy;
    Y y;
    std::cout << "xy:\n";
    std::cout << &xy << "\n";
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<Y*>(&xy) << "\n";
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<Y*>(dynamic_cast<X*>(&xy)) << "\n";
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<X*>(&xy) << "\n";
    std::cout << "y:\n";
    std::cout << &y << "\n";
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<XY*>(&y) << "\n";
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<Y*>(dynamic_cast<XY*>(&y)) << "\n";
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<Y*>(reinterpret_cast<XY*>(&y)) << "\n";
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<Y*>(static_cast<XY*>(&y)) << "\n";
```

may produce this output:

> xy:
> 0x7ffc0a570590
> 0x7ffc0a5705a0
> 0x7ffc0a5705a0
> 0x7ffc0a570590
> y:
> 0x7ffc0a570580
> 0
> 0
> 0x7ffc0a570590
> 0x7ffc0a570580

- Casts of the address of `xy` may give 2 different results.
- Casts of the address of `y` may give 3 different results.

**Summary:**
Pointer casts in C++ are far more complex than in C. The standard only guarantees behavior, but not the implementation. So, for example, a cast to an integer type might involve some bit manipulation - existing implementations don't do this because there's no point in doing this, not because it's forbidden. The main differences arise from C++ having multiple inheritance, virtual function and pointers to members.

*Caveat.* This long reply did not cover all aspects of pointer casts, most notably data alignment.  Also, the standard does not impose any limitation on the implementation of various pointers, and even the `reinterpret_cast` is not *guaranteed* to preserve the internal bit representation:

> Unlike static_cast, but like const_cast, the reinterpret_cast expression does not compile to any CPU instructions (**except when converting between integers and pointers or on obscure architectures where pointer representation depends on its type**).

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

See also:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: what you describe sounds like c-style casts or `reinterpret_cast`, but "you tell the compiler to switch off all its safeties" is not true for `dynamic_cast` nor for `static_cast`.

Comment: "Here comes dynamic_cast to cast a pointer in the potentially "dangerous" way along the inheritance tree." this is misleading. `dynamic_cast` returns a nullpointer when the cast did not succeed. Its not dangerous

Answer (score 1):

In case of classes and multiple inheritance, casting pointers can change the value (address) of the pointer as well.

Observe:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
    int foo;
};

class Bar {
    double bar;
};

class Baz: public Foo, public Bar {
    short baz;
};

int main() {
    Baz bz;
    std::cout << &bz << " " << static_cast<Bar *>(&bz) << " " << static_cast<Foo *>(&bz) << std::endl;
}
```

That's because the instances of the parent types are at different offsets of the derived object, they can't both sit at the same address.

This is upcasting (child to parent) which is always legal and static_cast is enough, for downcasting (parent to child) the extra checking of dynamic_cast is needed.

Answer (score 1):

> What does actually "conversion between pointers" mean ?

It means a conversion from pointer of one type to another pointer type.

> what will [`dynamic_cast<type_1*>(y)`] return ? A pointer of type *type_1 that points to the same object as y (or NULL, of course) ? Is this true?

That is true. The "same object" is correct in an Object Oriented sense. Although from strict C++ sense, the pointed objects of different types may be considered to be different objects.

> Is there anything more I should know to understand these castings between pointers ?

Yes, this is not the full extent of the rules relating to pointers and conversions. I recommend reading the documentation thoroughly and possibly some C++ books, in order to understand pointers and conversions.

Answer (score -2):

> what does casting between pointers mean ?

You change the meaning of the same data / object.

**Example 1:**

```
class Base {
public:
    void food() {printf("foo\n");}
}

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void bar() {printf("bar");}
}

int main() {
    Base * base = new Derived();
    base->foo(); // OK, it compiles
    base->bar(); // **NOK, syntax error**, even if you instantiated Derived class

    Derived * derived = static_cast<Derived *>(base);
    derived->foo(); // OK, it compiles
    derived->bar(); // OK, it compiles

    return 0;
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
int main() {
    char word[] = {'W', 'o', 'r', 'd', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'}; // array of 8 chars
    const char * ptrChar = static_cast<const char *>(word); // cast to "const char* "
    const int * ptrInt = reinterpret_cast<const int *>(word); // cast to "const int* "

    int lenChar = 0
    while (ptrChar[lenChar] != 0)
        ++ lenChar;
    printf("lenChar = %d\n", lenChar); // lenChar = 4

    int lenInt = 0;
    while (ptrInt[lenInt] != 0)
        ++ lenInt;
    printf("lenInt = %d\n", lenInt); // lenInt = 1

    return 0;
}
```

etc....
You should "play" more with pointers then you'll understand more about pointers and sense of conversion. It is a huge topic and essential in C/C++

dynamic casting is more complex. It requires understanding of run-time and compile-time, polymorphism, hierarchy, etc. In these 2 examples i didn't use dynamic casting because it would not work.

Comment: `const int * ptrInt = reinterpret_cast<const int *>(word); // cast to "const int* "` and a subsequent dereference of `ptrInt` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: It depends on your design.

Comment: Here is another example:
char * ptrChar = new char[10 * sizeof(int)];
int * ptrInt = reinterpret_cast<int *>(ptrChar);
The meaning and behavior are same as:
int *ptrInt = new int[10];

Comment: "The meaning and behavior are same as" - alas not. You might not have the correct alignment requirements for an `int` for starters. The other way round is fine, although `unsigned char*` would be a better choice.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` makes correct alignment :) If you paid attention, in example 2, at the end of array I've added 4-byte `0x00000000` instead of 1 byte '\0'. `unsigned char` normally is used to point that it is not a null-terminated string. Nothing more, except signed / unsigned meaning of data.